# The STM32 UART idle interrupt DMA reception method can only receive the first byte of data

Tags: stm32, dma

I am currently using STM32's UART idle interrupt to receive SBUS signals from a remote control receiver in DMA mode. However, after configuring this functionality, I have encountered issues where it doesn't work as expected. Upon debugging using KEIL, I found that the DMA only receives data once, and during the first full-speed run of the code, it receives only the first byte of data. Furthermore, during continuous operation, the data does not update, and I only receive the complete 25-byte datamainwhen I stop the program.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code below.

```
main.c
.....
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint8_t receive_buff[25]; 
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART6_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart6, (uint8_t*)receive_buff, 25);
  __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart6, UART_IT_IDLE);
  
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN artWHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
.....
```

```
uart.c

/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "usart.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
extern uint8_t receive_buff[25]; 
/* USER CODE END 0 */

UART_HandleTypeDef huart6;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart6_rx;

/* USART6 init function */

void MX_USART6_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART6_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART6_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART6_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART6_Init 1 */
  huart6.Instance = USART6;
  huart6.Init.BaudRate = 100000;
  huart6.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart6.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_2;
  huart6.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_EVEN;
  huart6.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart6.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart6.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART6_Init 2 */
  //HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart6, (uint8_t*)receive_buff, 25);
  /* USER CODE END USART6_Init 2 */

}

void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* uartHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(uartHandle->Instance==USART6)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART6_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART6_MspInit 0 */
    /* USART6 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART6_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**USART6 GPIO Configuration
    PC6     ------> USART6_TX
    PC7     ------> USART6_RX
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF8_USART6;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* USART6 DMA Init */
    /* USART6_RX Init */
    hdma_usart6_rx.Instance = DMA2_Stream1;
    hdma_usart6_rx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_5;
    hdma_usart6_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_usart6_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_usart6_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_usart6_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart6_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart6_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_usart6_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    hdma_usart6_rx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart6_rx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(uartHandle,hdmarx,hdma_usart6_rx);

    /* USART6 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART6_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART6_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART6_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART6_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

void HAL_UART_MspDeInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* uartHandle)
{

  if(uartHandle->Instance==USART6)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART6_MspDeInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART6_MspDeInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART6_CLK_DISABLE();

    /**USART6 GPIO Configuration
    PC6     ------> USART6_TX
    PC7     ------> USART6_RX
    */
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7);

    /* USART6 DMA DeInit */
    HAL_DMA_DeInit(uartHandle->hdmarx);

    /* USART6 interrupt Deinit */
    HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(USART6_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART6_MspDeInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART6_MspDeInit 1 */
  }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */
```

```
stm32f4xx_it.c
.....

void USART6_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART6_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE END USART6_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart6);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART6_IRQn 1 */
   USER_UART_IRQHandler(&huart6); 
  /* USER CODE END USART6_IRQn 1 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
void USAR_UART_IDLECallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    HAL_UART_DMAStop(&huart6);                                                     //停止本次DMA传输
    
    uint8_t data_length  = 25 - __HAL_DMA_GET_COUNTER(&hdma_usart6_rx);   //计算接收到的数据长度
    data_length = 0;
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart6, (uint8_t*)receive_buff, 25);                    //重启开始DMA传输 每次255字节数据
}



void USER_UART_IRQHandler(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
   // if(USART6 == huart6.Instance)                                   //判断是否是串口1（！此处应写(huart->Instance == USART1)
  //  {
        if(RESET != __HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart6, UART_FLAG_IDLE))   //判断是否是空闲中断
        {
            //USART6->SR;
            //USART6->DR;
            __HAL_UART_CLEAR_IDLEFLAG(&huart6);                     //清楚空闲中断标志（否则会一直不断进入中断）
            USAR_UART_IDLECallback(huart);                          //调用中断处理函数
        }
   // }
}

/* USER CODE END 1 */
......
```

I've seen this configuration online, and my UART4 is configured the same way. There don't seem to be any issues when sending data through a serial assistant. I'm using UART6, and the microcontroller model is STM32F407ZGT6.

Comment: Are the incoming data continuous, or are there IDLE frames between them? USAR_UART_IDLECallback() does not process the incoming data in any way, and it does not indicate that data are received, either.

Comment: You seem to be mixing using the HAL to handle the interrupt, and handling it yourself. This is generally a bad idea, since the HAL tends to clear flags and read data etc. By the time your code runs, the reason for the interrupt has been cleared.

Comment: Yes, the `USAR_UART_IDLECallback()` doesn't process data. I simplified the code for testing purposes. I can check if the `receive_buff` array has data in it while debugging to determine what data has been received. Unfortunately, the data only changes once, just like the image I provided.@wek

Comment: But my Serial Port 4 is configured the same way, and it works fine.@pmacfarlane